# Training Transformer with Tensor2Tensor Using Own Data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am trying to train a Transformer network using Tensor2Tensor. I am adapting the [Cloud Poetry](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/cloud-poetry-training-and-hyperparameter-tuning-custom-text-models-on-cloud-ml-engine) example to fit my own task, `kt_problem`, where I am mapping sequences of floats to sequences of floats instead of sentences to sentences.

I have adapted the `generate_data()` and `generate_samples()` functions according to the scattered specifications for using one's own data with tensor2tensor (e.g. the data generation [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/data_generators/README.md), line [174 of the `Problem` class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/data_generators/problem.py), etc.). They are as follows:

```
  def generate_samples(self, data_dir, tmp_dir, train):
    import numpy as np
    features = pd.read_csv("data/kt/features.csv", dtype=np.float64)
    targets = pd.read_csv("data/kt/targets.csv", dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(len(features)-1):
        yield {
                "inputs": list(features.iloc[i]),
                "targets": list(targets.iloc[i])
        }




  def generate_data(self, data_dir, tmp_dir, task_id=-1):
        generator_utils.generate_dataset_and_shuffle(
        self.generate_samples(data_dir,tmp_dir,1),
        self.training_filepaths(data_dir,4,False),
        self.generate_samples(data_dir,tmp_dir,0),
        self.dev_filepaths(data_dir,3,False))
```

defined within my class `KTProblem`.

After making this change, I can successfully run

```
PROBLEM='kt_problem'    #my own problem, for which I've defined a class

%%bash
DATA_DIR=./t2t_data     
TMP_DIR=$DATA_DIR/tmp

t2t-datagen \
  --t2t_usr_dir=./kt/trainer \
  --problem=$PROBLEM \
  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR \
  --tmp_dir=$TMP_DIR
```

and it generates a bunch of train and dev files. But when I try to train a transformer on it with this code,

```
%%bash
DATA_DIR=./t2t_data
OUTDIR=./trained_model

t2t-trainer \
  --data_dir=$DATA_DIR \
  --t2t_usr_dir=./kt/trainer \
  --problem=$PROBLEM \
  --model=transformer \
  --hparams_set=transformer_kt \
  --output_dir=$OUTDIR --job-dir=$OUTDIR --train_steps=10
```

It throws the following error:

```
ValueError: x has to be a floating point tensor since it's going to be scaled. Got a <dtype: 'int32'> tensor instead.
```

As you can see in `generate_samples()`, the data generated is `np.float64`, and so I'm sure my inputs shouldn't be `int32`. The stack trace (posted right below) is super long, and I've been going through every line listed and checking the type of the inputs to see where this `int32` input came into the picture, but I can't find it. I want to know (1) why, if my inputs are floats, why/how/where they're becoming floats, but mostly (2) generally, how does one debug code like this? My approach thus far has been putting print statements right before every line in the stack trace, but that seems such a naive way to debug. Would it be better to use VScode, or what is the lesson I need to learn here when a library `tensor2tensor`, in this case, is not behaving as I think it ought to, but I don't want to come to know intimately what every function in the stack trace is doing?

Stack trace:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Importing user module trainer from path /home/crytting/kt/kt
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/trainer_lib.py:240: RunConfig.__init__ (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.run_config) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
When switching to tf.estimator.Estimator, use tf.estimator.RunConfig instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Configuring DataParallelism to replicate the model.
INFO:tensorflow:schedule=continuous_train_and_eval
INFO:tensorflow:worker_gpu=1
INFO:tensorflow:sync=False
WARNING:tensorflow:Schedule=continuous_train_and_eval. Assuming that training is running on a single machine.
INFO:tensorflow:datashard_devices: ['gpu:0']
INFO:tensorflow:caching_devices: None
INFO:tensorflow:ps_devices: ['gpu:0']
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_task_type': None, '_task_id': 0, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x7f04151caba8>, '_master': '', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_environment': 'local', '_is_chief': True, '_evaluation_master': '', '_train_distribute': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1.0
}
, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_protocol': None, '_session_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 0.95
}
allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  optimizer_options {
    global_jit_level: OFF
  }
}
isolate_session_state: true
, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 1000, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 20, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_model_dir': './trained_model', 'use_tpu': False, 't2t_device_info': {'num_async_replicas': 1}, 'data_parallelism': <tensor2tensor.utils.expert_utils.Parallelism object at 0x7f0464512dd8>}
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator's model_fn (<function T2TModel.make_estimator_model_fn.<locals>.wrapping_model_fn at 0x7f0414891e18>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
WARNING:tensorflow:ValidationMonitor only works with --schedule=train_and_evaluate
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps 1000 or save_checkpoints_secs None.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
INFO:tensorflow:Reading data files from ./t2t_data/kt_problem-train*
INFO:tensorflow:partition: 0 num_data_files: 4
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/data_reader.py:275: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/data_reader.py:37: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:Shapes are not fully defined. Assuming batch_size means tokens.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/data_reader.py:233: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Setting T2TModel mode to 'train'
INFO:tensorflow:Using variable initializer: uniform_unit_scaling
INFO:tensorflow:Building model body
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/models/transformer.py:156: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/bin/t2t-trainer", line 33, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/bin/t2t-trainer", line 28, in main
    t2t_trainer.main(argv)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/bin/t2t_trainer.py", line 400, in main
    execute_schedule(exp)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/bin/t2t_trainer.py", line 356, in execute_schedule
    getattr(exp, FLAGS.schedule)()
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/trainer_lib.py", line 400, in continuous_train_and_eval
    self._eval_spec)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 611, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py", line 712, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 358, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1124, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1155, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1112, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/t2t_model.py", line 1414, in wrapping_model_fn
    use_tpu=use_tpu)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/t2t_model.py", line 1477, in estimator_model_fn
    logits, losses_dict = model(features)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 530, in __call__
    outputs = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 554, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/t2t_model.py", line 323, in call
    sharded_logits, losses = self.model_fn_sharded(sharded_features)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/t2t_model.py", line 400, in model_fn_sharded
    sharded_logits, sharded_losses = dp(self.model_fn, datashard_to_features)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/expert_utils.py", line 231, in __call__
    outputs.append(fns[i](*my_args[i], **my_kwargs[i]))
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/utils/t2t_model.py", line 428, in model_fn
    body_out = self.body(transformed_features)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/models/transformer.py", line 280, in body
    **decode_kwargs
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/models/transformer.py", line 217, in decode
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/crytting/kt/tensor2tensor/tensor2tensor/models/transformer.py", line 156, in transformer_decode
    1.0 - hparams.layer_prepostprocess_dropout)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 2979, in dropout
    return dropout_v2(x, rate, noise_shape=noise_shape, seed=seed, name=name)
  File "/home/crytting/anaconda3/envs/kt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 3021, in dropout_v2
    " be scaled. Got a %s tensor instead." % x.dtype)
ValueError: x has to be a floating point tensor since it's going to be scaled. Got a <dtype: 'int32'> tensor instead.
```

Comment: It looks like that error is about the parameter to dropout. Did you override hparams.layer_prepostprocess_dropout to be an integer?

Comment: Nope. It is set to be 0.6. That line in the stack trace refers to a multiline statement, however, where the decoder_input is int, as opposed to the dropout parameter. So I'm trying to figure out what I can do about that, since I only pass in floats as my targets and features.